# Multiple results in a list box are mis-aligned for printing

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have created a program for some class work and it all works fine, but I'm having some problems with the alignment of the multiple bits of info inserted into the list box on the same rows.

When I print it, it looks messy and also looks messy in the list box.

Is there anyway I can neaten it up a little? I've tried pad right with no joy and list views confuse the hell out of me. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Collections;

namespace Assignment2
{
    public partial class frmCalculator : Form
    {
        bool blnDot = false;
        double dbAllPoints = 0;
        double dbAllMoney = 0;
        public frmCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Glass");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Paper");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Beverage Cans");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Tins");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Milk Cartons");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Juice Boxes");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Plastics");
            ddbItems.Items.Add("Clothes");
        }

        private void txtInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a number!", "Error");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            if (e.KeyChar == '.')
            {
                if (blnDot == true) { e.Handled = true; }
                else { blnDot = true; }
            }
        }

        private void txtInput_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            txtInput.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String strItem = "";
            double dbMoney = 0;
            double dbPoints = 0;
            int intPoint = 0;
            double dbWeight = 0;

            if (((txtInput.Text == "")||(txtInput.Text=="Input the weight")||           (ddbItems.SelectedIndex==0)))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please input a weight into the textbox and make a   selection from the drop down box", "Error");
                }

        else
        {
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                intPoint = 7;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[1].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                intPoint = 8;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[2].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                intPoint = 10;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[3].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                intPoint = 10;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[4].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 5)
            {
                intPoint = 3;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[5].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 6)
            {
                intPoint = 3;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[6].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 7)
            {
                intPoint = 5;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[7].ToString();
            }
            if (ddbItems.SelectedIndex == 8)
            {
                intPoint = 6;
                strItem = ddbItems.Items[8].ToString();
            }

            dbWeight = Convert.ToDouble(txtInput.Text);
            dbPoints = intPoint * dbWeight;
            dbMoney = dbPoints * 0.01;
            dbAllPoints = dbAllPoints + dbPoints;
            dbAllMoney = dbAllMoney + dbMoney;
            lblTotals.Visible = true;
            lblTotals.Text = "You have " + dbAllPoints.ToString() + " points, and you have earned £" + dbAllMoney.ToString("0.00");
            lstResults.Items.Add(strItem + "   " + dbWeight.ToString() + "kg   " + dbPoints.ToString() + " points   £" + dbMoney.ToString("0.00"));
            txtInput.Text = "Input the weight";
            ddbItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
            blnDot = false;
        }
      }

    private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmWelcome frmWelcome = (frmWelcome)Application.OpenForms["frmWelcome"];
        frmWelcome.Close();
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to reset everything?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.No) return;
        txtInput.Text = "Input the weight";
        lstResults.Items.Clear();
        ddbItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
        lblTotals.Text = "";
        lblTotals.Visible = false;
        blnDot = false;
    }

    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int intMax;
        intMax = lstResults.Items.Count;
        String[] arrResults = new String[intMax];
        int intLoop;

        for (intLoop = 0; intLoop < intMax; intLoop++)
        {
            arrResults[intLoop] = lstResults.Items[intLoop].ToString();
        }

        Array.Sort(arrResults);
        lstResults.Items.Clear();

        for (intLoop = 0; intLoop < intMax; intLoop++)
        {
            lstResults.Items.Add(arrResults[intLoop]);
        }

        printDocument1.Print();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        String strLine = "";
        int intLoop;
        Font pfont = new Font("Verdana", 18, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        int intLine = 75;

        strLine = "Item                    Weight  Points    Money";
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strLine, pfont, Brushes.Black, 75, intLine);
        strLine = "";
        intLine = intLine + 30;
        intLine = intLine + 30;

        for (intLoop = 0; intLoop < lstResults.Items.Count; intLoop++)
        {
            strLine = strLine +lstResults.Items[intLoop];
            e.Graphics.DrawString(strLine, pfont, Brushes.Black, 75, intLine);
            intLine = intLine + 30;
            strLine = "";
        }

        intLine = intLine + 30;
        strLine = lblTotals.Text;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(strLine, pfont, Brushes.Black, 75, intLine);
        strLine = "";
        intLine = intLine + 30;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `DataGridView` control instead of a `ListBox` since you are trying to display "column" information.

Likewise, when printing, you should be doing the `DrawString` for each column as well so that they line up properly.

If you want to continue with what you are doing, then you should use a mono-spaced font like Courier, not Verdana, and count the spaces between then lengths of the words.

Comment: the brief requires a list box so i will try changing the font. . would I then use the padright or shall I just manually insert spaces when adding items to the drop down box?

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor, Yes, PadRight would work.  Subtract the max number of characters the "column" should hold from the length of the string.